# Scope of Gmail Contextual Gadget

Tags: gmail-contextual-gadgets

Is posible in a Gmail Contextual Gadget add an email address in the "cc" field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No !

You can only read properties from the incoming mail that triggers your gadget. You cannot make any modifications to an e-mail.